# Is there a way to send function in the body of POST method

Tags: python, c#, rest, api-design

I have a web app and web API server for my game that has one state per year. The game works like this:

1. New Game (year 0)
2. Player selects next move on web
3. Player hits submit, API is called
4. API returns next state (year 1), this displays some data on web
5. Player selects next move on web
6. Player hits submit, API is called API returns next state (year 2)
7. etc.
8. Game ends when the game hits predefined year

The api looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public GameState Post([FromBody] (GameState currentGameState, PlayerSelection playerSelection))
{
   var nextGameState = _gameLogic.GetNextStep(currentGameState, playerSelection);
   return nextGameState;
}
```

Now what I would love to do is write an AI in Python that will learn to play the game by using different strategies. The way I see it I can either recode the whole game in Python so I can play it over and over again, or I can call API from Python that will play the game, while AI will decide how to play.

The first option is infeasible since I don't want to duplicate code, while the second option seems terrible because playing 10,000 games will probably take up a lot of time. The question I have, if there is some way to actually send function over the API so that in my controller I have a new function:

```
[HttpPost]
public GameState Post([FromBody] Func<GameState, PlayerSelection> gamePlay)
{
  var currentGameState = _gameLogic.GetInitial();

  while (currentGameState.Year < 50)
  {
     var nextMove = gamePlay(currentGameState);
     currentGameState = _gameLogic.GetNextStep(currentGameState, nextMove);
  }
}
```

So the gamePlay represents a choice based on the current data. This would significantly improve how many API calls AI has to do, while also keeping the logic on the web server. It would also allow AI to parametrize the gamePlay function. I think this might require some kind of special parser or some meta language. Are there any frameworks to help solve a problem like this?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "send a function"...what exactly would this function do? Why not just implement the required functionality in the API? Maybe you just need the python to be able to send a more detailed list of settings to the server, to control the potential behaviour? It's a little unclear what you're envisaging, precisely.

Comment: Normally when person plays a game, they make some strategy, a set of rules on how to behave based on the current game state. So if you imagine a game like Tic-Tac-Toe, the gamePlay could be anything from "randomly assign a cross on empty square" to "check the longest current streak of crosses with empty square and mark that or otherwise assign randomly" or eve n "neural network matrix will pick the square". This would be easy to do if the Post service was directly called from code, I would just pick method and pass it as an argument, but I'm not sure I can send that over the wire.

Comment: You might be over-complicating this. Realistically the python needs to have an understanding of the game state (same as would be visible to the player), work out what the best possible move is, using its own logic, and then just send its next move to the API. The API shouldn't care whether the move was initiated by human thinking or computer thinking. The API could perhaps help computer-controlled players by providing a machine-readable data set of the current game state (as visible to the authenticated player) as well as the visual version that human players see in the page.

Comment: The main reason I would want to pass the strategy through API is that I could reduce the number of calls to APIs from e.g. 1,000 (every step for every game) to virtually 1 per strategy. If we're testing thousands of strategies, that's thousands of API calls instead of millions. I could also instead just create a new controller with specific strategies, so that Python only passes parameters (data) instead of functions and accomplish the same thing. But then I will need to always change my API when I want to change what my AI is capable of.

Comment: In other words, I think Python (or any caller) should handle AI logic and web server should handle game logic.

Comment: ok but then you'd need a long-running process on the server capable of being the client, listening for moves from other players (I assume it's potentially a multi-player game?) and then using the supplied strategy function to decide what move to make. Also how would the AI then get involved? All you've done is supply a pre-set strategy, in C#. You can't then use the python AI to genuinely react to the changing situation of the game, because you've ceased all contact with the client side until the game ends. I don't think the concept works at all.

Comment: To expand: In your proposed scenario, all you'd be able to do is use python AI's knowledge of _previous_ games to inform a strategy for the next one. It can't intervene mid-game. The strategy function would make all decisions, using a pre-set algorithm. If you wanted to do that, you might as well get python to pre-generate these algorithms before you deploy the C# code, then you can implement them in C# and provide them as pre-set options for a computer player. But that's not real-time AI, it's just the same sort of semi-AI bots that games have been using for decades.

Comment: To genuinely have the AI decide what to do in the next move, it needs to know the current state of the game, so it can then apply its knowledge of similar scenarios in previous games, in order to decide what the next best move would be in this game. That's how machine-learning works best, rather than pre-defined strategies. (I'm assuming you've chosen python because it's popular for machine-learning / data science stuff - but maybe I've misunderstood and you really do just want a pre-defined "computer player" bot which can use a preset strategy to try and play?)

Comment: My game would be a single player investment simulator game, which through randomness generates market investment opportunities. I imagine my strategy would be something like a neural network analyzing all the relevant data to make investment decision. Therefore one strategy = one neural network, which basically in some way maps state to nextMove (I called this gamePlay function). This can map various different states to various different nextMoves. Therefore I don't need to react to the state, because my "reaction" is to put it through neural network and that's it.

Comment: So what I would want from AI (coded in Python or F#, it doesn't really matter) to come up with the strategy (function from gameState -> nextMove) and then the server would "play" the game, finish several play throughs and then return the results of all these games. I could then some up the score of these games and compare different neural networks/strategies. Basically the neural network would be complex enough to generate nextMove for any possible gameState, but simple enough to be sent over the API.

Comment: `my "reaction" is to put it through neural network` yeah but for that you need access to the neural network, which I'm not sure you'll have if you do it on the server side. how is the neural network represented on the python/F# side? Is it self-contained in a single function? Sorry it's not something where I know much about the specific details.

Comment: There are certainly neural network libraries in Python and F#, but generally neural network can be thought of as a matrix calculation like:

Comment: There are certainly neural network libraries in Python and F#, but generally neural network can be thought of as a matrix calculation, e. g.:

nextMove.InstrumentASelection = (currentState.InstrumentAReturns * 0.44 - currentState.InstrumentBReturns * 0.65)
nextMove.InstrumentBSelection = (currentState.InstrumentAVolatility * 1.3 + currentState.InstrumentBAnotherDescription + 2)

And then there are algorithms (in neural network libraries) that attempt to maximize/minimize something (like final score) by changing these weights (0.44, -0.65, etc.).

Comment: In other words, it's easy to calculate what neural network gives predicts (in our case neural network = strategy, which "predicts" next state), and what's hard is to ensure that neural network = strategy actually plays the game well. That's what Python/F# libraries will do, they implement the algorithms that ensure best weights are found. Needless to say you need try many weights before the algorithm finds an optimal one. So what I would like to do is send the equation over the API. Note that neural network can flexibly use many properties, multiplications between them etc.

Comment: Hm. It's certainly possible to generate snippets of C# as a string have that then be executed by the server, but realistically there are going to be some limits to the complexity of the code you can execute by that method.

Comment: I wonder really if this is an X-Y problem. You're worried about a performance issue due to the number of API calls you'd need to make during a game. Your proposed solution is to send some logic to the server once which would then enable the whole game to run server-side. This is likely to be problematic - the solution is non-obvious and likely to be extremely complex to get right. So how about a different solution - why don't we make the client-server communication system more efficient. Have you come across websockets and SignalR before?

Comment: My question was aimed at being more academic as the solution I seek is a bit "out there". I was inspired by functional programming, in which functions are treated as first class objects, and would so naturally solve my specific problem. However, I'll still be grateful for any tips on how to make the communication as quick and handle as many requests as possible. I've also used SignalR for notifying UI from server, but I'm not aware of how the SignalR would help with quicker responses or more throughput.

Comment: Oh and I didn't explain this, but after the game finishes I would also love to compare the results of the player with result from some simple (predefined) strategies. So my preferred solution would also solve this pretty easily.